# Adding custom path to gcc command

Tags: c, gcc, geany

i know there a a few posts already about this but I do not seem to be able to get it right.

I am working on a shared project using geany and gcc. The file structure looks something like this:

```
`/Documents/.../project/ main directory of project with makefile`
`/Documents/.../project/src here are some sourcefiles and headers`
`/Documents/.../project/src/extended here are some other source and header files`
`/Documents/.../project/src/tools other header and source files`
```

now lets say I am working on a sourcefile in /tools that includes from extened with 
`#include"/extended/some_header.h"`
because my makefile is configured to search for files from `/src`. However when I am trying to compile the file I am working on right now (by using geany compile option which just calls gcc) I cannot compile it obviously because it cannot find `/extended/some_header.h` in the `/src` folder. I have tried adding
`-iquotes/Documents/.../project/src`
to the gcc call by geany but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @EugeneSh. IMHO, the linked question is not of very high quality. Do you mind providing another one? (I'm almost sure there is a better dupe, but blame me, i'm feeling too lazy after a long day..)

Comment: So I guess I'll have to answer this myself..

Comment: you just need to have gcc knows about your include folder, which can be done by passing `-I` option(upper i). the object files should be compiled one by one and dealt with finally by linker.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr In order the linker to deal with objects, they should be generated first.

Comment: @EugeneSh.yeah, that's what i am referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-I` flag tells the `gcc` compiler where it should look for the *header* files. Passing the `-Idir` to the compiler is appending the `dir` path to the head of the search list, effectively making this path higher priority than the previously (or system) defined paths. As for the source path - there is no such an option for `gcc` itself. Each source file passed to the compiler has to have it's path (absolute or relative). In order to work it around, a `Makefile` can be provided, defining a list of files to be compiled.

Comment: I think in the case above a Makefile is the only really working solution.